# How to implement statuses in messanger app with fire base?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to create a messenger app with flutter and for back end I goning to use `FireStore DataBase`. I need to implement statuses like: `typing` and `online`. I can set statuses, but if for example connection with network was lost how i can change statuses?

I know that in case we use `WebSocet` we can write func `onClose` for but i didnt find it on `FireStore`. Is there some thing like that or other way?

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence